# Access Laravel localhost site in network pc without running artisan serve

Tags: laravel, xampp

I have a laravel project that is on the server pc and i want to access it using other pc that is connected on the same network without running php artisan serve in the server pc.

I tried using virtualhost and it works on the server pc but in other pc on the network getting this error page laravelproject.test’s server IP address could not be found.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\247_timesheet\public"
    ServerName timesheet.test
    ErrorLog "logs/timesheet.test-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/timesheet.test-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Host file

127.0.0.1     timesheet.test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to connect using the IP address of the server?

Comment: Yeah this way is possible